# get exit code of a background process that completed a while ago

Tags: process, background, ksh, exit-code

This may not be a completely new topic but I ran into a little bit odd situation.

I'm processing about 1000 files in a loop by kicking off a script in background. I want to take some actions on the files based on the exit code each process returns. By the time I go in a loop to wait for each process to complete I found that some of the process were already done. I modified the script to wait only if pgrep finds a process and just assumed a process completed successfully otherwise. The problem is- I have to know exit code of each process in order to take action on the corresponding file. Any ideas?

`pid_list=()
for FILE in $SOME_FOLDER 
do
    (process with FILE as parameter) &
done

for pid in "${pid_list[@]}"
do
    if pgrep $pid; then     #process could have just completed as we got here
        if wait $pid; then
            echo "process $pid successfully completed!" >> $logfile
        else
            echo "process $pid failed!" >> $logfile
            fnc_error_exit
        fi
    else
        echo "assumed that process $pid successfully completed but I DON'T KNOW THE EXIT CODE!" >> $logfile
        continue
    fi
done`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot solve your problem exactly.

Since I do not know the exact situation of you, anyway, could you try another method using parent and child scripts ?

For example, the topmost script is like this:

```
  for FILE in $HOME/*.txt
  do
    parent.sh $FILE  &
  done
```

Then, the parent.sh is like this:

```
  child.sh  $1
  RC=$?
  case $RC in
     0 ) echo Exit code 0 for $1 >> parent.log
     ;;
     1 ) echo Exit code 1 for $1 >> parent.log
     ;;
     * ) echo Other Exit code $RC for $1 >> parent.log
     ;;
  esac
```

The child script is like this:

```
   grep -q hello $1
```

Then, the parent.sh will handle every exit code of the child.sh

All files will be handled by a parent.sh, without a missing handling.